# Kali Linux USB Live Boot Not Working

Tags: linux, boot, live-usb, kali-linux

I downloaded the Kali Linux ISO 64-bit off of this page:

- http://www.kali.org/downloads

Then, I used the [Kali Linux Live USB Install Procedure on this page](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-live-usb-install) for Windows. I boot my computer from my USB drive, and I get the following screen:

[image: ss#1]

I click Live (amd64), the first option. Sorry it's not the best picture. Boots well and lo and behold I get to the main screen, and for a second it appears to work:

[image: ss#2]

All is going well, but after a second my computer just reboots, and I'm back to the first picture. I do not understand what is going on! So, how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have a 64bit processor?

Comment: Yea it's an AMD A10-6800K 64-bit Processor.

Comment: Output of `lspci` and `lsusb` please. Or you can check wireless and other devices for Linux hardware compatibility. I don't suppose there's anything useful in `/var/log/kern.log`?